# How to collect Stream<Map<K,V>> into Map<K,List<V>> using java 8?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

I have a stream of `Map<String,Double>` that I want to collect into a single `Map<String,List<Double>>`. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First you need to flatten your stream of maps into a stream of map entries. Then, use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) along with [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)):

```
Map<String,List<Double>> result = streamOfMaps
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

Say i had:

```
Stream<Map<String, Double>> mapStream
```

Then the answer is:

```
mapStream.map(Map::entrySet)
         .flatMap(Collection::stream)
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```